# Is there a way to remove Log messages for Urban Airship

Tags: android, logging

I am building an app using Urban Airship for push notifications. I want to suppress Log messages but don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the log level in the [AirshipConfigOptions](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/android/latest/reference/com/urbanairship/AirshipConfigOptions.html). By default Urban Airship uses `debug` for development apps (inProduction = false) and error for production apps (inProduction = true). You can set the log level programmatically:

```
 AirshipConfigOptions options = new AirshipConfigOptions.Builder()
                .setDevelopmentLogLevel(Log.ASSERT)
                .setProductionLogLevel(Log.ASSERT)
                ...
                .build();

 UAirship.takeOff(this, options);
```

Or if you use airshipconfig.properties:

```
developmentLogLevel = ASSERT
productionLogLevel = ASSERT
```

Or if you use an xml file:

```
<AirshipConfigOptions
    productionLogLevel = "NONE"
    developmentLogLevel = "NONE"
    ... />
```

You can find more info in the [Urban Airship Android docs](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html#create-airship-config-options).

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation.